# Activate UISearchBar when the controller is loaded

Tags: swift, keyboard, uikit, ios9, uisearchbar

I have the following SearchController:

```
class SearchController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating
```

The implementation works well, but I have to tap on the search bar to start searching every time I load the controller. What I'd like is to activate the search bar once SearchController is loaded. I have tried with:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ...
    ...

    self.resultSearchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

I also tried with:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.resultSearchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

But the search bar remains deactivated and the keyboard won't show up. What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This works (not sure why it's not working for you):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let mySearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.titleView = mySearchController.searchBar
        mySearchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        mySearchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Comment: if I add the following "resultSearchController.active = true; resultSearchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()" then it *almost* works: the search bar is activated but the cursor prompt is still not visible (meaning, it won't accept key presses unless I tap in the search bar field.)

Comment: FWIW, Apple's own TableSearchwithUISearchController example does the same thing. I have modified the code to disable state restoration and always force searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder(). It exhibits the same behavior as my app. :-/

Comment: Are you displaying the `UISearchBar` in the `titleView` of the navigation bar?

Comment: I've tried with 1) tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar and 2) navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar. Same thing.

Comment: Create a new Xcode single view project. In the storyboard embed the view controller in a navigation controller (to get the navigation bar). Then replace the contents of ViewController.swift with what I posted.

Comment: Yep, your demo works, but with a table view attached, etc. it simply doesn't. I have now three demo apps that won't show the keyboard. Have you tried with Apple's example? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableSearch_UISearchController/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: I downloaded the project, and added this after line 39:
`[self.searchController.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];` and tested it on the simulator and a physical iPhone, and as soon as the app loads, the search bar has focus.